# Правильная реализация заданий для игрока

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. Помогите советом или примером.

Хочу реализовать миссии(а ля сюжетка) и заказы(типа побочные задания). Миссии имеют неограниченное время выполнения а заказы в свою очередь напротив. В основном есть 4 типа заданий которые я хочу использовать и там и там. Но помимо этих основных типов заданий есть ещё другие задания которые подходят только для миссий(сюжетки) и только для заказов(побочки). Конечно же за выполнения что миссий и что заказов игроку приходит награда.

Как мне правильно реализовать? Что будет в class BaseTask? Или что то сделать через интерфейс?
Какой паттерн лучше применить и нужно ли?

Помогите пойти по правильному руслу, что бы эта система task-ов была гибкая и понятная по всем канонам программирования. Потому что я понимаю, что если я сразу буду писать плохо то потом это обязательно вылезет боком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Task
{
    ITaskCondition
    TaskStatus
    TaskInfo
}
```

В `ITaskCondition` условия выполнения и провала задания.

```
public interface ITaskCondition
{
    event Action Updated;
    bool CompleatConditionMet ();
    bool FailConditionMet ();
    void Stop();
}
```

Может быть условие на выполнение группы условий `убей 5 Goblin за 10 минут` или условие на выполнение одного из условий, например `убей или договорись`. По сути разные стратегии `AndCondition` и `OrCondition`, которые тоже `ITaskCondition`. Можно сделать обёртку для обратного условия `NotCondition` и комбинируя разные стратегии получать сложные условия.

```
убей 10 Goblin или Golin King не трогая Goblin Scout

AndCondition
    OrCondition
        KillCondition Goblin, 10
        KillCondition GoblinKing, 1
    NotCondition
        KillCondition GoblinScout, 1
```

---

```
public class KillCondition : ITaskCondition 
{
    public event Action Updated;
    private readonly UnitType _targetType;
    private readonly int _targetCount;
    private int _currentCount;

    public KillCondition (UnitType type, int count)
    {
        _targetType = type;
        _targetCount = count;
        UnitManager.Killed += OnUnitKill;
    }

    public bool CompleatConditionMet ()
    {
        return _targetCount >= _currentCount;
    }

    public bool FailConditionMet () 
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void Stop () 
    {
        UnitManager.Killed -= OnUnitKill;
    }

    private void OnUnitKill (Unit unit)
    {
        if (unit.Type == _targetType)
        {
            _currentCount++;
            Updated?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

`Status` это просто градусник для условия.

```
public class TaskStatus
{
    public event Action<TaskStatusType> Changed;
    private ICondition _condition;

    public TaskStatusType Type { get; private set; }

    public Status (ICondition condition)
    {
        _condition = condition;
        _condition.Updated += Update;
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        if (Type != TaskStatusType.InProgress)
            return;
        if (_condition.CompleatConditionMet())
            Change(TaskStatusType.Complicated);
        else if (_condition.FailConditionMet())
            Change(TaskStatusType.Failed);
    }

    private void Change (TaskStatusType status) 
    {
            _condition.Stop();
            Type = status;
            Changed?.Invoke(Type);
    }
}
```

Ну и всякие константы вроде `Discription`, `Reward`, иконок и прочего можно засунуть в какой-нибудь тип данных типа `TaskInfo`.

Наверное как-то так.